# Can't pass a string into my Rust function from Ruby

Tags: c, ruby, rust, ffi

I'm trying to call a function which accepts a string, written in Rust.

The Rust code is then compiled to C and included in my Ruby code via the FFI gem.

When I call the Rust function and pass a string I get nothing.

Rust code:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn speak(words: &str) {
  println!("{}", words);
}
```

Ruby code:

```
require 'ffi'

module Human
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib '../target/release/libruby_and.dylib'
  attach_function :speak, [:string], :void
end

Human.speak("Hello, we are passing in an argument to our C function!!")
```

Comment: Have you seen [*The Rust FFI Omnibus*](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/string_arguments/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Types), `:string` represents a null-terminated string, which is `char *` in C. The `&str` argument is not equivalent to that type: a `&str` is a compound value, composed of a pointer and a length.

The safest solution is to change your Rust function to accept a `*const c_char` instead. You can then use [`CStr::from_ptr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.from_ptr) and [`CStr::to_str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.to_str) to work with it more easily.

Alternatively, you could define a struct in your Ruby code that contains a pointer and a length, and pass that to the Rust function. However, there's no guarantee that this struct will always match the memory layout of a slice, so to be 100% safe, you should define the equivalent struct in your Rust code (with `#[repr(C)]`), then, using the fields of this struct, call [`slice::from_raw_parts`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html) to construct a slice (`&c_char` or `&u8`), which you can then turn into a `&str` with [`str::from_utf8`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html).